# Why CustomStringConvertible protocol not working for Int?

Tags: ios, swift

```
public func +<T: CustomStringConvertible>(lhs: T, rhs: T)->String{
    return lhs.description+rhs.description
}

let a:String = "A"

let i:Int = 0

print(a+i)
```

I am overloading '+' operator for CustomStringConvertible types. String and Int both confirms CustomStringConvertible protocol but it gives an error: "binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'Int' print(a+i)". It working fine when I apply it to 'String'+'NSNumber'.
don't know what is going behind the scene. why it is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is firstly (believe it or not) `String` doesn't conform to `CustomStringConvertible`. You'll therefore want to conform it yourself in order for it to return `self` for `description` (probably easier than writing another overload to deal with strings independently).

```
extension String:CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        return self
    }
}
```

Secondly, you need *two* generic parameters for your `+` overload, in order to allow it to accept different types for both parameters, while ensuring that both parameters conform to `CustomStringConvertible`:

```
public func +<T: CustomStringConvertible, U:CustomStringConvertible>(lhs: T, rhs: U)->String{
    return lhs.description+rhs.description
}
```

Comment: Thanks @originaluser2

Comment: @Tailor Happy to help :)

Comment: String now conforms to CustomStringConvertible https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string